# Hidden import in PyInstaller not working?

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller, mysql-connector-python

I am trying to create an executable using PyInstaller.
Important files for my problem are:
`main.py` and `dbinterface.py` which are both located at the root level.

In `dbinterface.py` I am doing: `import mysql.connector` which would need to be added as an hidden-import to PyInstaller as I assume.

I tried this by adding `--hidden-import pyinstaller mysql.connector` and also by changing the spec-file which I am honestly not sure about whether I did this correctly.

PyInstaller show in the command line following line in it's output: `4448 ERROR: Hidden import 'mysql.connector' not found`

Comment: AFAIK if you’re using an `import` statement it isn’t a hidden import - this is really for code that uses importlib, or Needs dlls

Comment: additional information: I am importing dbinterface.py in main.py

Comment: Yes there’s no problem as long as it’s explicit `import` statements. See the pyinstaller documentation second para of this page https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html#analysis-finding-the-files-your-program-needs

Comment: About hidden imports the doc says: Some Python scripts import modules in ways that PyInstaller cannot detect: for example, by using the __import__() function with variable data, using imp.find_module(), or manipulating the sys.path value at run time

Comment: what could then be the problem? running the executable gives me following error message:  `  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
[1640] Failed to execute script main`

Comment: And the source code runs fine from the commandline? you're not running from within an IDE are you? Break the problem down - start by writing a little python file hello.py which just prints "Hello, World" and make sure that a) it runs, and b) when you run pyinstaller on it the result runs OK. Then add `import mysql.connector` to it and repeat the check.

Comment: I already tried this. I am running from inside an IDE, there my code is working fine.

Comment: Ok so chances are pyinstaller doesn’t have the same python env as your IDE. Get your code to run from the commandline.

Comment: yeah, that actually worked! Thanks a lot, got really in trouble with this :D

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had to install `mysql-connector-python` globally in Python. It's not working if you have them only instaled in your virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

You most probably need to also install your PyInstaller into the virtual environment and run PyInstaller from the virtual environment, not the one that is installed globally